# What is the memory hit of initializing canvases

Tags: javascript, html, caching, canvas

I'm creating my own personal rendering engine, and I'm currently upto implementing a caching function to cache paths to canvases in memory (not in the DOM), and use drawImage to get them.
I'm undecided in which approach I should use.

Few big canvases with multiple images cached to it, and their location on the canvas stored in another object.

Or many small canvases for each image.

Naturally, I know many small canvases would give better retrieval performance, but I'm not sure if initializing many small canvases would use up a lot more memory than few bigger canvases.

Also, using the many small canvases approach, we could be talking hundreds of small canvases in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide way too few details to formulate a good response so here's a generic response.

Performance:

Keep in mind that a canvas is just a writable bitmap. The fastest writes to a canvas are blits from existing img elements and/or existing canvas elements.  Store your static paths in img elements. Store your dynamic paths in canvas elements. But, "hundreds of small canvases" is not workable!

Memory Usage:

Your question title indicates a need to optimize memory.  In this case, *not caching to memory at all* might be best.  The canvas is fast--just redraw the paths as needed and avoid the extra memory used by in-memory images or canvases.